# Realizar Un Programa en C# o en PHP que realice Integrales Definidas

Tags: php, c#

Necesito realizar un programa que haga integrales definidas, estuve días viendo como hacer, pero no se me ocurre niguna, ya me sé todos los métodos para resolver integrales, pero no se me ocurre una manera de hacerlo en un programa. Hice uno así, pero me dijeron que no sirve

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Resultado de la Integral Definida</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Resultado de la Integral Definida</h1>
    <?php
      // Obtener los valores del formulario
      $funcion = $_POST['funcion'];
      $limite_inferior = $_POST['limite_inferior'];
      $limite_superior = $_POST['limite_superior'];

      // Calcular la integral definida utilizando el método de Barrow
      function calcularIntegral($funcion, $limite_inferior, $limite_superior) {
        // Implementa aquí el cálculo de la integral utilizando el método de Barrow sin utilizar librerías de PHP

        // Ejemplo de cálculo utilizando una aproximación numérica
        $n = 1000; // Número de puntos para la aproximación
        $h = ($limite_superior - $limite_inferior) / $n; // Tamaño del intervalo
        $resultado = 0;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
          $x = $limite_inferior + $i * $h;
          $resultado += eval("return $funcion;") * $h;
        }

        return $resultado;
      }

      // Mostrar el resultado
      $resultado = calcularIntegral($funcion, $limite_inferior, $limite_superior);
      echo "<p>El resultado de la integral definida de $funcion en el intervalo [$limite_inferior, $limite_superior] es: $resultado</p>";
    ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: entonces lo que pretendes es que te demos la idea (Opinion) o que te lo hagamos???

Comment: solo necesito una idea de como realizar el cálculo matemático en uno de los dos lenguajes, porque como ya sabrás las integrales requieren de Integración, pero como hacer que el programa inetegre, además de que me pidieron que lo haga sin librerias de php o c#

Comment: Lectura altamente sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: el codigo en tu consulta lo hiciste tu???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es posible resolver el problema como lo propones, o por lo menos es demasiado complejo para analizar aquí, porque [Barrow](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_fundamental_del_c%C3%A1lculo#Segundo_teorema_fundamental_del_c%C3%A1lculo) necesita primero la integral indefinida para entonces resolverla aplicándole los límites numéricos.
(...) A menos que te conectes por API a Wolfram Alpha, a GPT, o similares; y solicites primero la solución de la integral indefinida.

Sin embargo, una integral definida se puede resolver por [métodos numéricos](https://www.google.com/search?q=metodos+num%C3%A9ricos) (esto es todo un curso en la Universidad), sin necesidad de resolver la ecuación simbólicamente. Y para ello hay varios métodos de [integración numérica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integraci%C3%B3n_num%C3%A9rica).

Pongo como ejemplo, [Regla de simpson 1/3](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-simpsons-13-rule/), pero tu puedes emplear cualquier otro.
Se intentará resolver `Integral(2x^2 - 3x)` | `lim(2, 3)`

```php
<?php

function evalfunc($x) {
    return (2*$x*$x) - (3*$x);
}

function simpsons_13($liminf, $limsup, $intervalo) {
    $tam_interv = ($limsup - $liminf) / $intervalo;
    
    $x = array();
    $fx = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<=$intervalo; $i++) {
        $x[$i] = $liminf + $i * $tam_interv;
        $fx[$i] = evalfunc($x[$i]);
    }
    
    $res = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<=$intervalo; $i++) {
        if (($i == 0) or ($i == $intervalo))
            $res += $fx[$i];
        elseif ($i % 2 != 0)
            $res += 4 * $fx[$i];
        else
            $res += 2 * $fx[$i];
    }
    return $res * ($tam_interv / 3);
}

// #####
// NOTA: $intervalo debe ser un número par.
echo simpsons_13(2, 3, 8); // 5.1666666
```

Comment: es que es complejo el ejercicio, por eso pedí ayuda, pero ya avancé un poco